# iTunes crashes when connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes

I have already posted once, but the problem is so weird. Initially, when it started crashing (all of a sudden), I reinstalled iTunes and it was working fine. After a week, it happened again. I reinstalled it again. Two weeks later, it started crashing again. Then after some research on Google, it turns out that when I switch off Wi-Fi, it works fine.

By the way, I tried opening iTunes in safe made (command+shift+click). It crashed on safe mode as well!

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5822899?tstart=0

These are the results from console at the time of crashing:

```
04/09/16 7:25:28.805 PM iTunes[426]: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue
04/09/16 7:25:35.946 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.iTunes.118752[426]) Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15
04/09/16 7:25:36.060 PM UserNotificationCenter[428]: *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
04/09/16 7:25:37.421 PM spindump[383]: Saved hang report for iTunes version 12.4.3 (12.4.3) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/iTunes_2016-09-04-192537_Ns-MacBook-Pro.hang
```

Comment: You know what, I reinstalled it again. And its still not working :(

Comment: Can you open the "Console" app (search for it in spotlight). Then within Console try to filter results on "iTunes" around the time the crash happens. Do you find any log messages here, if so make a screenshot and post them here

Comment: When in iTunes, go to the Account Menu and Sign out of your AppleID. Quit iTunes. Start Wifi. Open iTunes. Does it crash?

Comment: @edwardmp see the edited post